# Keybord events are not working in text boxes of an iframe inside Flex application

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a text box in an iframe which is included in a Flex application.

My keyboard events are not getting triggered while i am typing in the text box like Home,End ,Up down arrows..

```
<input id="addressSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search Location" >
```

Please help me to get resolved this issue.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring for what events triggered when you keypress using monitorEvents?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar ..Thx for your reply.
No I have not included the monitorEvents..I am working in html part in an iframe..not allowed for flex side edits.

Comment: Could you tell us which kind of element or component is used in your flex to show the html content ?